# change RewriteBase depending on domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to set RewriteBase depending on the domain, right now RewriteBase is set to ~/myusername/folder/site.com, if someone opens http://mydomain.com it redirects to (shared HTTPS) https://something.hostingproveder/~myusername/folder/site.com , now I want to use my real domain without https and if I'm using it I need to change RewriteBase to / or to completely delete it...

Is there something in .htacces that can check which domain is used and set RewriteBase depending on domain.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to dynamically set RewriteBase in .htaccess.

However, if you have access to your httpd.conf [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501536/kohana3-different-htaccess-rewritebase-and-kohana-base-url-for-dev-and-product) is one way to do it using [AccessFileName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#accessfilename)

Even if you do not have access to your httpd.conf, the same post above has a clever way to use Environment variables (answer by mozillalives) to achieve a similar result.